# How to get a list of sites that a user is a member of?

Tags: support, feature-request, sites

After spending many hours trying to post a question using [/questions/add](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-question) and repeatedly getting the error message "*The account associated with the access_token does not have a user on the site*", I finally realized that users have to join individual sites to post to it. I was attempting to post a question to a site which I have not joined because my site selector displayed all Stack Exchange sites from [/sites](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites). Is there a way to return only the sites which the user has joined to prevent the interface from leading an unsuspecting user into a dead end as I, the programmer, was?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have a token, then you can use the [`/me/associated`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-associated-users) network route to get the associated site for the authorized user. There's a [similar route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users) that takes a network account ID and does not require an active access token.